# Python code chunk generation with instances

Tags: python, eval

I have a simple function that generates some code chunks on the fly using:

```
chunk = eval("(lambda " + ','.join(variables) + " : " + expression + ")", namespace)
```

This is later on run using:

```
apply(chunk, variableValues)
```

This works fine with basic expressions like

```
variables = ["a", "b"]
expression = "a != b"
variableValues = [5, 6]
```

However, now I want to replace these simple variables with instances and the expression will be a function call. I have tried lots of things, but I have no idea how to get this working... Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
variables = ["cellA", "cellB"]
expression = "cellA.isEqual(cellB)"
variableExpression = [Cell(4, 5), Cell(5, 3)]
```

Where Cell is just some class I made that implements isEqual().

EDIT: I cant skip the eval part of this. This is for a simple program that solves constraint satisfaction problems. Part of the program is to take in these constraints on the fly and create these code chunks.

Comment: Please don't do this. Neither eval nor exec should be used if it's possible to avoid them, as they create massive security holes, and make debugging hard. Is there a reason why you can't write your expressions and statements as functions you can parametrize with e.g. functools.partial? Also, there are the rich-comparison methods available in python, maybe you could consider using these instead of isEqual.

Comment: It's impossible to say why this isn't working without seeing a complete code sample.  I agree with deets that this is likely overkill and there are probably simpler ways to do it.  Also, don't implement `isEqual`, implement `__eq__`, and then use `cellA == cellB`.

Comment: I'm not worried about the security of debugging this is for a simple constrain satisfaction solver, main point of this simple program is that it can take constrains on the fly and convert it to code chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This should be a comment but is too long)

Works fine for me in Python 2.7 and 3.2:

```
>>> variables = ["cellA", "cellB"]
>>> expression = "cellA.isEqual(cellB)"
>>> chunk = eval("(lambda " + ','.join(variables) + " : " + expression + ")")   
>>> chunk
<function <lambda> at 0x6ffffcaa6e0>
>>> class Cell(object):
...   def isEqual(self, other):
...     return 27
...
>>> chunk(Cell(), Cell())
27
```

If you have a problem you need to show some code that demonstrates the problem, not just vaguely describe what you think the problem might be.

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea why this didn't work earlier? This is basically that I wrote in my opening post which also what I tried in my program, but it kept on crashing.

Answer (score 0):

For your actual problem, you could simply use the unbound method isEqual.

```
 class Cell(object):

     def __init__(self, *args):
         self._args = args

     def isEqual(self, other):
         return self._args == other._args


 a = Cell(1,2)
 b = Cell(3, 4)


 f = Cell.isEqual
 print f(a, b)
```